# RegEx to match the patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a requirement

```
.domain
.domain.com
.domain.com/path
.domain.com:443/path
domain.com
domain.com/path
domain.com:443/path
domain
/path
:443/path
```

Should all be true

However

```
.
./path
.:443
*.domain
*.domain/path
*.domain:443/path
/
:443
*/path
anything with ? in it
```

should all return false.

I came up with the below in JS. But, after a few modifications I am completely lost..

```
/^\.?[^:\/]([\da-z\.-]+)\.?([a-z\.]{2,6})?(:[0-9]+)?([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

My test stub looks below:

```
console.log(urlRegExp('*.domain/path'));
console.log(urlRegExp('*.domain:443/path'));
console.log(urlRegExp('/'));
console.log(urlRegExp(':443'));
console.log(urlRegExp('*/path'));
console.log(urlRegExp('domain.com?q=a'));

function urlRegExp(){ 
  return /^\.?[^:\/]([\da-z\.-]+)\.?([a-z\.]{2,6})?(:[0-9]+)?([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/.test(arguments[0]) + " " + arguments[0];  
}
```

I am unable to handle all the listed strings with this pattern. Whenever I change something to make something pass, another string fails. I am a beginner and just started into understanding RegEx deeply with the cookbook. However, it might take a while and I need it to be done sooner. Any help or guidance would be awesome.

Current Results:

should return true:

```
true .domain
true .domain.com
true .domain.com/path
true .domain.com:443/path
true domain.com
true domain.com/path
true domain.com:443/path
true domain
false /path  -- should be true
false :443/path  -- should be true
```

should return false:

```
false . 
false ./path
false .:443
true *.domain -- should be false
true *.domain/path -- should be false
true *.domain:443/path -- should be false
false /
false :443
false */path
false domain.com?q=a
```

Comment: This is impossible. As an example: The 3rd of the `true` rules `.domain.com/path` is forbidden by the nineth of the `false` rules `*/path` (given a reasonable interpretation of `*`). What you *you* think `*` should mean for your scheme to make sense?

Comment: Why does this specific set of rules exist? What exactly are you trying to validate? Input how? To where? Under what circumstances?

Comment: The tests seem to indicated that `*` is a litteral `*`. Is it? Or does it mean it *anything*?

Comment: The exercise seems to be pattern recognition in your test set, rather than finding a regular expression for it. Try to figure out the rules first.

Comment: It's a URL redirection form. The user should not input a URL pattern that violates above rules. URL pattern, not just the URL. So, a * means a literal *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this...

```
/^[./:a-z]([0-9]+\/)?[a-z]+[^?]*$/
```

Explained here...

```
/^                 # Start regex, and start matching
[./:a-z]           # starts with dot, slash, colon or a-z
([0-9]+\/)?        # optionally has multi-digit number followed by slash
[a-z]+             # has one or more letters next
[^?]*              # has zero or more characters that are not `?`
$/                 # end of matching and end regex
```

Hard to know the specifics of what you are aiming for

Tests in...

### Coffeescript

```
rex = /^[./:a-z]([0-9]+\/)?[a-z]+[^?]*$/

for str in """
.domain
.domain.com
.domain.com/path
.domain.com:443/path
domain.com
domain.com/path
domain.com:443/path
domain
/path
:443/path
""".split /[\r\n]+/
    console.log "Should be true - is #{if str.match rex then 'true ' else 'false'} #{str}"

for str in """
.
./path
.:443
*.domain
*.domain/path
*.domain:443/path
/
:443
*/path
domain.com?
domain.?com
?domain.com
""".split /[\r\n]+/
    console.log "Should be false - is #{if str.match rex then 'true ' else 'false'} #{str}"
```

and in...

### Javascript

```
var rex, str, _i, _j, _len, _len1, _ref, _ref1;

rex = /^[./:a-z]([0-9]+\/)?[a-z]+[^?]*$/;

_ref = ".domain\n.domain.com\n.domain.com/path\n.domain.com:443/path\ndomain.com\ndomain.com/path\ndomain.com:443/path\ndomain\n/path\n:443/path".split(/[\r\n]+/);
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  str = _ref[_i];
  console.log("Should be true - is " + (str.match(rex) ? 'true ' : 'false') + " " + str);
}

_ref1 = ".\n./path\n.:443\n*.domain\n*.domain/path\n*.domain:443/path\n/\n:443\n*/path\ndomain.com?\ndomain.?com\n?domain.com".split(/[\r\n]+/);
for (_j = 0, _len1 = _ref1.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
  str = _ref1[_j];
  console.log("Should be false - is " + (str.match(rex) ? 'true ' : 'false') + " " + str);
}
```

Both output the same...

```
Should be true - is true  .domain
Should be true - is true  .domain.com
Should be true - is true  .domain.com/path
Should be true - is true  .domain.com:443/path
Should be true - is true  domain.com
Should be true - is true  domain.com/path
Should be true - is true  domain.com:443/path
Should be true - is true  domain
Should be true - is true  /path
Should be true - is true  :443/path
Should be false - is false .
Should be false - is false ./path
Should be false - is false .:443
Should be false - is false *.domain
Should be false - is false *.domain/path
Should be false - is false *.domain:443/path
Should be false - is false /
Should be false - is false :443
Should be false - is false */path
Should be false - is false  domain.com?
Should be false - is false  domain.?com
Should be false - is false ?domain.com
```

Comment: That works great. Now I'm going through it repeatedly to know the magic.. :D

Comment: How do I handle the last two?

`domain.com?` and `domain.?com`

Comment: Sorry, the last two are handled correctly now. I updated the answer just after I posted, but forgot to update the `console.log` output. The `?` is handled by `[^?]` which is a negated character set, meaning anything except `?`. So the whole string matches only a certain bunch of characters at the start, and anything except `?` up until the end of the string.

Comment: I should also mention, that the javascript is compiled directly from the coffee-script, and could be written much more simply if written by hand.

Comment: On a totally unrelated subject, which OS you're using? The `\r\n` in the `split` function made me wondering if it's Windows?

Comment: I used `\r\n` to cover any case - force of habit to try to make my regexes portable - although I think `\n` only would suffice for javascript on any operating system. Also, it is not `\r` followed by `\n` but a character set of `\r` and `\n`, where I am saying any number of consecutive `\r` or \`n`s of either type are my delimiter, so even `\r\r\n\r\n\n\n` would act as delimiter.